# Cut mysql data when selecting

Tags: mysql

I have a table with **"***unique***"** values. The problem is that the program, which adds these values also adds 3 different postfixs to the value (2 characters in the end of the value). As a result, I have three variable with three postfixs. So i need  get only unique values from bd - somehow sort it out without the last two characters. Are any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Camera_id should you return (first,last,maximum,minimum???) if rows have one "unique" value but different Camera_id's. Try something like this:

```
select 
LEFT(camera_name,LENGTH(camera_name)-2), max(camera_id)
from cameras
where site_id=1
group by LEFT(camera_name,LENGTH(camera_name)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrieve the values with the `first letter` only?

```
SELECT   DISTINCT SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 1,1) a
FROM     tablename
ORDER BY a
```

can you show sample records? it helps a lot when your asking question.